# What's wrong with this method for copying a file in Python?

Tags: python

I don't understand why my new file has a bunch of special characters in it that were not in the original file. This is similar to ex17 in *Learn Python The Hard Way*.

```
#How to copy data from one file into another

from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

from_data = open(from_file, "r").read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(from_data)

print "Checking if output file exist..... %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Hit return to continue or Cntl C to quit"

#keyboard input
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, "r+")
out_file.write(from_data)

print "Okay all done, your new file now contains:"
print out_file.read()

out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You must open the files in binary mode (`"rb"` and `"wb"`) when copying.

Also, it's in general better to just use [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) and not re-invent this particular wheel. Copying files well can be complex (I speak with at least [some authority](http://obsession.se/gentoo/)).

Comment: Well the author forgot to mention that part lol. Let me try that real quick.

Comment: well using rb or wb doesnt seem to work for me. What happens is when I go to print out the new file i hear a beep from my computer then on the console window i see big blank area with special characters on the last line. Then in my text editor i see that that new file contains the data but has nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull.... at the end of the last line. Whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewinding the file pointer back to the beginning using `seek` before you read the results.

```
out_file = open(to_file, "r+")
out_file.write(from_data)

print "Okay all done, your new file now contains:"
out_file.seek(0)
print out_file.read()
```